# using CSS in an android project

Tags: android, css, xml

I have many xml pages that repeat lines of code, i feel like it would be much cleaner if I used a css page, I have looked it up, but in all the examples, it uses webview, which is something a freind told me to avoid when designing apps for phone use.

can I use a css page to reduce repetition and make my code cleaner? or does it have a side effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use CSS natively in Android, however you have a number of choices.

You can either use the built in styling options for android and provide a styles.xml with styles you can reuse throughout the app.

[Android Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Another option, if you're set on using CSS is to make use of the pixate library:

[Pixate Android](http://www.pixate.com/blog/2013-12-20-android-update-3/index.html)

Whilst this isn't production ready yet, it does provide a way for you to use CSS to style your widgets.